# How to perfectly discretize a parametric surface in a 3D grid?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, 3d, surface

I have a parametric surface `s : R -> R -> (R,R,R)`, where R is a bounded real number in the range `[0..1]`. The surface is contained on the unit cube `(0,0,0), (1,1,1)`. I have subdivided that cube in several slices, forming a 3D array/grid. I want to know, given that surface, what points on the grid are intersected by it. In other words, I need a function:

```
discretize 
    :  (surface : R -> R -> (R,R,R)) 
    -> (cubeDim : (Uint, Uint, Uint))
    -> [(Uint, Uint, Uint)]
```

The naive way to do it would be to simply sample `surface` in regular intervals. If you pick a small interval, though, you'll have holes. If you pick a big interval, you'll do more work than necessary.

Are there known, fast algorithms for that?

Comment: You could begin with a regular sampling. Then, approximate the surface as a triangular mesh from these samples. Finding the cells that are intersected by a triangle shouldn't be too hard. But it is probably easier to just do the point-based sampling. Maybe with a step length that adapts to the geometry (i.e. such that the maximum distance to the next sample is at most the cell size).

Comment: you can't really do this without some kind of limit on how fast surface(u,t) changes with u and t

Comment: Look into CGAL and exact geometry. http://www.cgal.org/exact.html